# Blank page when trying use direct injection with ProductRepositoryInterface class

Tags: dependency-injection, di.xml

I am fairly new to Magento and following a tutorial on Udemy to learn how to develop on Magento 2.

I am attempting to overwrite the ProductRepositoryInterface, however whenever I add the preference tag in my di.xml file I am getting a blank page.

When I remove the preference tag my di.xml works fine.

I've attached my code below.

I have tried cache:clean and setup:upgrade with no luck.

If somebody is able to stear me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thanks, Pete!

Controller/Page/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php

namespace PHPete\FirstModule\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use PHPete\FirstModule\NotMagento\PencilInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $pencilInterface;
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PencilInterface $pencilInterface, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository){
        $this->pencilInterface = $pencilInterface;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        echo 'Hello World<br>';
        echo get_class($this->productRepository);
    }
}
```

Model/CustomImplementation.php

```
namespace PHPete\FirstModule\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class CustomImplementation implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{

    public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false);

    public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

    public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

    public function delete(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product);

    public function deleteById($sku);

    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
}
```

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="PHPete\FirstModule\NotMagento\PencilInterface" type="PHPete\FirstModule\NotMagento\BigPencils" />
    <preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="PHPete\FirstModule\Model\CustomImplementation" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well about 30 seconds afterwards I realised my error.

My tutor's IDE had automatically populated `CustomImplementation` class, whereas mine hadn't. So I copied and pasted the code from the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` interface

All I had to do was add the body to each function like so:

```
<?php

namespace PHPete\FirstModule\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class CustomImplementation implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{

    public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false){

    }

    public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false){

    }

    public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false){

    }

    public function delete(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product){

    }

    public function deleteById($sku){
}

    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria){

    }
}
```

I hope this answer helps anybody else wrapping their head around Magento2